# Synchronous iteration not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline, async.js

I'm trying to iterate through an array and create records for each iteratee. This is what I am doing like mentioned here at another question:

```
async.each(data, (datum, callback) => {
  console.log('Iterated')

  Datum.create({
    row: datum,
  }).exec((error) => {
    if (error) return res.serverError(error)
    console.log('Created')
    callback()
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, it results in this:

```
Iterated
Iterated
Iterated
Created
Created
Created
```

Not this as wanted:

```
Iterated
Created
Iterated
Created
Iterated
Created
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `async.eachSeries()`.

Comment: @Thomas that did it :) Please answer my question so I can price it :) Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[async.eachSeries()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) will run one iteration at a time and wait for each iteration to be terminated before pursuing the next step.

> I create an unique user friendly identifier before each creation (like 1, 2, 3 and so on). For that, I've to query the data base to find the latest identifier and increment it which is not available because the records are nearly created at the same time.

This sounds like here's the bottleneck. I don't like running async code in series because this usually slows processes down. How about this approach:

- Due to `data` you know how many identifier you'll need.
- implement a function in the backend that doesn't create a single but `n` such identifier at a time *(including the necessary incrementing, etc.)* and return that Array to the frontend. Now you can run your regular requests in paralell using/mapping that array of precomputed IDs to the data-array.

This should reduces the runtime from `(createAnId + request) * data.length` pretty much down to to the runtime of a single iteration. Due to the fact that all these requests can run in paralell, and therefore mostly overlap.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Datum.create is an asynchronous function. 
The forEach whips through each of the three elements of the array, logging them in turn. and since JavaScript won't block prior to the asynchronous events being returned, you get each of the console.logs in turn. 
Then after *some* amount of time, the results come in and "created" is logged to the console.

Comment: You are right, `Datum` is a asynchronous function from Sails.js.

Comment: Are you familiar with promises? Since you have no control over *when* (or if) an async request will return, you could set up each call as a promise with the next call chained on as a ".then"

Comment: Don't you mean "JavaScript won't block while the asynchronous events are waiting to be fired" rather than "JavaScript won't block while the asynchronous events are processing" as javascript is not "processing" anything?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an asynchronous data processing library. For the result you intend to get, you need to process the data synchronously. Here's how you could do it:

```
data.forEach(function(datum) {
  console.log('Iterated')

  Datum.create({
    row: datum,
  }).exec((error) => {
    if (error) return res.serverError(error)
    console.log('Created')
    callback()
  })
})
```

You may also want to remove the `callback` function entirely now since the data is processed synchronously.

Comment: Thank your, tried your solution with no luck. And yes, `Datum` is an asynchronous function provided by Sails.js.

Comment: That makes sense. I was assuming Datum.create was a synchronous operation. Why do you need the process to be synchronous?

Comment: Good question. I create an unique user friendly identifier before each creation (like 1, 2, 3 and so on). For that, I've to query the data base to find the latest identifier and increment it which is not available because the records are nearly created at the same time.